# Matlab surface hsv colormap

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I'm plotting the phase of a signal using a 2D view of surface plot but I'm having troubles with two things:

the first one, if I use `colormap('hsv');` why does it works for one plot while it doesn't for the next one if both have the same property?
The other question, how can I smooth the transition between one color to the next one? In order to have a rainbow effect and not this kind of sharp transition.

```
figure(2),surf(X,Y,E),'edgecolor', 'none');
colormap('hsv');
view(2);
xlim([-3 3]); ylim([-3 3])
title('Phase delta');
figure(3),surf(X,Y,A-E),'edgecolor', 'none');
colormap('hsv');
view(2);
xlim([-3 3]); ylim([-3 3])
title('Phase sum-delta');
```

[image]

Comment: Read what a [mcve] is. You know this is data dependant, and you showed no data, therefore you can not get help

Comment: Regarding your second question, you can use the command 'shading interp' to smooth the color transitions in your plot.